# Calculating Bounding Rect

Tags: c++, 2d, marmalade

I'm trying to clone space invader of atari and I have problem with bounding rect calculations.. the rect is not correctly bounded.. maybe I have problem with the transformations

```
void Barrier::Render()
{

    if (mBarrierImage)
    {
        CIwFMat2D Transform;
        // Build transform
        Transform.SetIdentity();
        Transform.SetRot(0);
        Transform.ScaleRot(1);
        Transform.SetTrans(Position);
        Iw2DSetTransformMatrix(Transform);

        Iw2DSetColour(0xffffffff);

    CIwFVec2 pos = Transform.t;
    BoundingRect.x = Position.x;
    BoundingRect.y = Position.y;
    BoundingRect.w = (float)mBarrierImage->GetWidth();
    BoundingRect.h = (float)mBarrierImage->GetHeight();
    Iw2DSetColour(0xff0000ff); // Set red
    Iw2DDrawRect(CIwFVec2(pos.x, pos.y), CIwFVec2(mBarrierImage->GetWidth(), mBarrierImage->GetHeight())); // Draw red outline
```

Comment: Are you sure your Position.{x/y} are top-left corner and not center?

Comment: @tkausl I'm using Position{x,y} for movement of the image.

Comment: What tkausl means, is that maybe Position{x,y} points to the center of the image, instead of it's top-left coordinate. If you set position.x to 0 AND position.y to 0, do you see the entire image or just a quarter?

Comment: I will test it and will tell you the results. but is bounding rect calculations is correct ? like I have to set the position of the image to the bounding rect's x,y ?

Comment: Well, *if* your position is the top-left corner, then yes. if its the center, then you have to subtract (width/2) from x and (height/2) from y.